# Get first image after one special sting with PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, curl, preg-match

I have a simple question. Just imagine we have this HTML string bellow :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="one.png">
            <div class="something">

            KEYHERE

            <img src="address.png">

            Some text       
            Lorem ipsum ... 
            <img src="two.png">
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, there is a `KEYHERE` in the top HTML code.

I have a php variable like this :

```
$key = "KEYHERE";
```

Now, i want to get the first image `src` (address) exactly after that key.

For example , about that top code, i need to get the `address.png` address in my php codes to use it.

How can i do it?

Comment: How are you calling this? Are you using PHP cURL to get the above HTML? Is this called in the same page? Explain a bit more what is happening here, please.

Comment: @BrandonWhite the HTML page may be accessed from any way! that is not important, the thing that is important, is that we have a HTML codes, and want to get first img address from next of our Key :)

Comment: Have you done anything to attempt this? You could you a regular expression, or even simply get strpos of `$key` and remove everything before it then find the strpos of the first `<img` and try to extract the src.

Comment: "accessed from any way" means that you are failing to explain a key bit of information required to answer this question.

Comment: @Diodeus You can imagine the HTML code is in a variable and it is static without CURL or any other thing. If you have any idea to access the img right after that key i love to know your idea. thanks.

Comment: @Diodeus Good idea :-?  If it's possible , give me an example please. Thanks.

Comment: @Diodeus The way of aquisition of the HTML string doesn't matter for parsing, nor should you care about it. It is certainly not a "key bit of information required to answer this question". OP is right.

Answer (score 3):

The following code uses the native DOM parser in PHP ([`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)) and the [`XPath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) implementation to find nodes.

This piece of code will first find your keyword. Once it has found the keyword it will check the siblings of the node to find the first `img` tag (if any) on the same level.

```
// gets the first matching sibling (first image found in the dom tree on the same level)
function getFirstImageTag(DOMNode $node) {
    while ($node->nextSibling) {
        $node = $node->nextSibling;
        
        if ($node->nodeName !== 'img') continue;
        
        return $node->getAttribute('src');
    }
}

// parses the document / finds the keyword in the html string
function parse($html, $keyword) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    
    // you can use a more strict check here if you are sure the keyword is the only thing in the textnode
    $textNodes = $xpath->evaluate("//text()[contains(.,'$keyword')]");
    
    foreach ($textNodes as $textNode) {
        if (trim($textNode->textContent) === $keyword) {
            return getFirstImageTag($textNode);
        }
    }
}

echo parse($content, 'KEYHERE');
```

<sub>The above example is based on your example HTML where the keyword is in a textnode. If this isn't the case the above code should be easy to "fix" to your needs.</sub>

<sub>Note: this answer makes a lot of assumptions. Will it always be a textnode? Will the `img` tag always be in the same branch of the tree (even on the same level)? Will there be any possibility there are other nodes between the keyword and the `img` tag.</sub>

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/8GkLhW

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$key = 'Test';
$html = '<html><body>Test <img src="http://example.com" /></body></html>';

$tmp = substr($html, strpos($html, $key));
$start = strpos($tmp, 'src="')+5; 
$tmp = substr($tmp, $start);
$end = strpos($tmp, '"');

echo substr($tmp, 0, $end);
```

http://runnable.com/U8behz5Pfi4HipDa/get-first-image-after-one-special-sting-with-php

Comment: Nothing personal but I would hate to be the person inheriting this piece of code

Comment: Yay to not using a regex! Boo to not using a parser! Yay to having an example that works. Boo to having an example that doesn't work with most HTML. Yay to... I'not sure. Boo to all the things.

Comment: So, If the length of the key changes, The code changes again!

Comment: I thought of going for a parser, but for this situation it really is over the top. Just working on the data given in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use regular expressions here.

You can use the following code:

```
<?php

$content = '<html>
    <body>
        <img src="one.png">
            <div class="something">

            KEYHERE

            <img src="address.png">

            Some text       
            Lorem ipsum ... 
            <img src="two.png">
            </div>
    </body>
</html>';


preg_match('/(?:KEYHERE\s*)<img(?:\s*)src="(\S*)"/i',$content, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

to get `address.png`

Comment: better use `src="[^"]+"` to ensure you do not get some crazy results out of `.*` i.e. for `KEYHERE <img src="address.png"> <img src="address2.png">` your expression matches `address.png"> <img src="address2.png`

Comment: thanks dear Marchin, IF we have Two Keys , what to do ?

Comment: @Pap Then you can use `(?:(?:KEYHERE|KEYTWO)\s*)` instead of `(?:KEYHERE\s*)`

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Very thanks, i see you have used `|` in you last comment. So, if i need to check Both of Key1 and Key2 (if both of them) then find first image what to do? I think this `|` means `OR` , How can we use `AND` command here ? To have both of them at same time.

Comment: If you need them both before img you simple should put here the whole string that needs to be before img. In `|` annotation it means that it will find all img that have before work keyhere or keytwo